# Upload a file with puppeteer in Jest

Tags: chromium, jestjs, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am using Jest and have puppeteer set up as in [this repository](https://github.com/xfumihiro/jest-puppeteer-example), which is linked to from the [Jest documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/puppeteer.html).

I am trying to write some automated smoke tests on a WordPress website using puppeteer. One of the tests attempts to upload an image to the WordPress Media Library.

This is the test:

```
it('Create test media', async () => {
  // go to Media > Add New
  await page.goto(`${env.WP_HOME}/wp/wp-admin/media-new.php`)
  const display = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const el = document.querySelector('#html-upload-ui')
    return window.getComputedStyle(el).display
  })
  if (display !== 'block') {
    // ensure we use "built-in uploader" as it has `input[type=file]`
    await page.click('.upload-flash-bypass > a')
  }
  const input = await page.$('#async-upload')
  await input.uploadFile(testMedia.path)
})
```

The file input field's value is populated as expected (I know this because if I save out a screenshot after the call to `uploadFile` it shows the path of the file in the input), and the form is submitted, however when I go to view the media library there are no items.

I have tried the following amendments to the `uploadFile` part of the test, to no avail:

```
// 1. attempt to give time for the upload to complete
await input.uploadFile(testMedia.path)
await page.waitFor(5000)
```

```
// 2. attempt to wait until there is no network activity
await Promise.all([
  input.uploadFile(testMedia.path),
  page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})  
])
```

```
// 3. attempt to submit form manually (programmatic)
input.uploadFile(testMedia.path)
page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#file-form').submit())
await page.waitFor(5000) // or w/ `waitForNavigation()`
```

```
// 4. attempt to submit form manually (by interaction)
input.uploadFile(testMedia.path)
page.click('#html-upload')
await page.waitFor(5000) // or w/ `waitForNavigation()`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that file uploading doesn't work when connecting to a Browser instance via WebSocket as in [`jest-puppeteer-example`](https://github.com/xfumihiro/jest-puppeteer-example). (GitHub issue here: [#2120](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2120).)

So instead of doing that just use `puppeteer.launch()` directly when setting up your test suite (instead of via the [custom "Jest Node environment"](https://github.com/xfumihiro/jest-puppeteer-example/blob/master/puppeteer_environment.js)):

```
let browser
  , page

beforeAll(async () => {
  // get a page via puppeteer
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  page = await browser.newPage()
})

afterAll(async () => {
  await browser.close()
})
```

You also then have to manually submit the form on the page, as in my experience `uploadFile()` doesn't do this. So in your case, for the WordPress Media Library single file upload form, the test would become:

```
it('Create test media', async () => {
  // go to Media > Add New
  await page.goto(`${env.WP_HOME}/wp/wp-admin/media-new.php`)
  const display = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const el = document.querySelector('#html-upload-ui')
    return window.getComputedStyle(el).display
  })
  if (display !== 'block') {
    // ensure we use the built-in uploader as it has an `input[type=file]`
    await page.click('.upload-flash-bypass > a')
  }
  const input = await page.$('#async-upload')
  await input.uploadFile(testMedia.path)
  // now manually submit the form and wait for network activity to stop
  await page.click('#html-upload')
  await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
})
```